# In java collections return type are List

Tags: java

In java collections return type are List type only why list is considered as a more suitable return type

Comment: As opposed to what? Would you prefer that they return `Exception`?

Comment: what's the question exactly?

Comment: Are you asking why return `List` instead of an implementation of it, like `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of saying `List` type only, it is better to put it as interface type only (`List` is interface and `ArrayList` is one of the List implementation).

> Why?

Because it gives you freedom to change implementation details in future with minimal impact on client layer.

For example:

If you have initially:

```
List<String> myTempList = new ArrayList<String>();
return myTempList;
```

At some point thought to change implementation from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`.

```
List<String> myTempList = new LinkedList<String>();
return myTempList;
```

Client who is using `myTempList`  won't need to do any changes unless it is doing explicit casting.